# Best practice when upgrade VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN Subversion client

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

Before I can test https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15916380/vb-script-to-retreive-access-rights-reporting-from-viusal-svn/15940120?noredirect=1#comment22725112_15940120
to perform live migration from version 1.6.3 to 3.0.5 (latest release), **Could you share is there any rule of thumb and best practice for success this upgrade activity?**

I have gone through for pre and post checklist http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00036/
But still have some concern as listed

> 1.The existing Repositories is on `E:\Repositories`, should I make a backup copy? and can we select the existing Repo during the installation? (The existing VisualSVN Server is installed at the default localtion `C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server`
>
> 2.I Believe there is the downtime for our user to access SVN service during upgrade, usually how long will it take to complete?
>
> 3.Can our user still work on the old TortoiseSVN? Our user currently on TortoiseSVN 1.6.15 and  suggest to upgrade 1.7.11. Should we upgrade the client first?

I have more than 500+ users, so I need to collect as much as information to discuss and get agreement on this upgrade.

Comment: Create a virtual machine, install VisualSVN 1.6.3 and actually test the upgrade path. And yes, you should make a backup before doing a production upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

VisualSVN 3.0.5 is the latest version of the Visual Studio extension, not of a server. As of today, the latest VisualSVN Server version is 2.5.9.

VisualSVN Server 1.6.3 is linked against Subversion 1.5.5 while 2.5.9 comes with Subversion 1.7.9. Note that Subversion 1.7 introduced a lot of user-visible changes both on the client and server sides. So I strongly recommend an administrator to read the [Apache Subversion 1.7 Release Notes](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html).

Answering your questions:

1. The best practice here would be to always make a backup. However it's not really required. Just select your current repositories location in the installer and proceed,
2. It won't take more than a couple of minutes,
3. Users can use older Subversion clients after you upgrade the server.

Users will be required to checkout new working copies or upgrade old ones since due to changes in working copy format. Check the [TortoiseSVN 1.7 Release Notes](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html#wcformat).